# How to use Kramdown in GitLab

Tags: markdown, gitlab, kramdown

I haven't found the instruction how to change GitLab's RedCarpet to Kramdown.
on Kramdown I have found how to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby
sudo gem install kramdown
```

But the Usage page was absolutly non-understandable for me

```
require 'kramdown'
puts Kramdown::Document.new(text).to_html
```

What is language? Where I have to write it?

Comment: The language is [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/). You just installed it via `apt-get`. But I'm not sure where that code needs to go…

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's no longer applicable, see @David Planella's answer.

Answer (score 1):

For those landing on this old question, [GitLab migrated from RedCarpet to Kramdown](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/gitlab-docs/merge_requests/108) as its Markdown engine with the 11.5 release (2018-11-22). Enjoy! ;-)